# Downloading files with wget through torsocks results in 403 error

Tags: download, wget, tor

When downloading files using wget through torsocks I am hit with a 403 error, why does this happen?  Setting the user agent does, and the website is fine when I access the URL through the tor browser.  Other answers on the internet suggest the previous, but I think that tor provides another layer of complication.